# this is my stored procedure to check that there should n't same email id

Tags: asp.net, sql

Here I need to get the message. If I enter email id in the application there I should get the message that email is already exists how it is possible?

```
IF not EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Resource WHERE Email= @Email)
if(@status = 'Insert')
BEGIN
     Insert into resource(FirstName,LastName,Password,Role,Email,Phone,OrganisationID) 
     values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Password,@Role,@Email,@Phone,@OrganisationID)
END
```

Comment: Unique constraint on `Resource.Email`.

Comment: you should also add unique constraint to table.

Comment: How should the message be displayed? `SELECT 'Failz0r!'; RETURN` ? :p You can also look at `RAISERROR()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ELSE` block:

```
IF not EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Resource WHERE Email= @Email)
BEGIN
    if(@status = 'Insert')
    BEGIN

      Insert into resource(FirstName, LastName, Password, 
                           Role, Email, Phone, OrganisationID) 
      values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Password,
              @Role,@Email,@Phone,@OrganisationID)
    end
END
ELSE  
BEGIN
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

**Or:** You can move the condition to the `IF` like this:

```
IF not EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Resource WHERE Email= @Email)
   AND @status = 'Insert'
BEGIN
      Insert into resource(FirstName, LastName, Password, 
                           Role, Email, Phone, OrganisationID) 
      values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Password,
              @Role,@Email,@Phone,@OrganisationID);
END
ELSE  
BEGIN
    RETURN 0; -- It depends on the return type 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not Exists (select Email from Resource where Email= @Email)
begin
 set @status='Insert'
Insert into resource(FirstName,LastName,Password,Role,Email,Phone,OrganisationID) 
values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Password,@Role,@Email,@Phone,@OrganisationID)
end
else begin  set @status='EmailExists='+@Email end
```